# Visual Studio doesn't apply Powershell module changes on Pester unit test execution

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, pester

I have created a "Powershell Module Project" within Visual Studio 2015 and wrote some functions for the module. When I make changes to the `.psm1` file and try to unit test these changes with the Pester framework (`.test.ps1` file) the new changes are not applied during the test. This happens in Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017.

I've tried:

- "Clean Solution", "Rebuild Solution" and "Build Solution"
- "Unload Project" and "Reload Project"
- "Close Solution" and "Open Solution"

The only solution I've found so far is to reopen the IDE.

Where might this issue originate from and is there any other solution to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change a PowerShell module that has already been loaded, those changes don't automatically apply to the currently running PowerShell session because the module has been loaded in to memory (and this remains true even if you manually run `Import-Module <modulename>` as PowerShell sees the module is already loaded and does nothing).

The workaround is to either use `Remove-Module` first and then reload it with `Import-Module`, or use `Import-Module <modulename> -Force`.

You could add either of these solutions to the top of your Pester test file to ensure it's always reloading the module before testing it.

Comment: Thanks! Now I get why this is happening. I decided to go with "-Force" since the "Remove-Module" might run into issues when executed for the first time(?).

Comment: I think there is some reason why `Remove-Module` is preferred but i've never found the `-Force` method to cause me any issues. You could do `If (get-module <modulename>) { remove-module <modulename> }` to stop an error being thrown if it's not already loaded.